# Merge Sort issue ending results not the same

Tags: java, arrays

I have a MergeSort Algorithm that I created to output a random assortment of numbers. However I am having some issue with it:

1.) I don't understand why my "After" result is returning with different resulting numbers and/or multiple same numbers ex:

```
Before sorting: 
66 71 45 79 69 95 95 93 83 28
After sorting: 
28 28 83 93 95 95 83 93 95 95
```

Am I missing a simple error in my code?

2.) Also How can I show the # of swaps that this algorithm is performing.

Any suggestions, improvement and/or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I am working with:

```
public class MergeSort
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int A [] = new int [10];
        populateA(A);

    System.out.println("Before sorting: ");
    printA(A);

    A = merge_sort(A);

    System.out.println("\nAfter sorting: ");
    printA(A);

}

public static int []merge_sort(int [] B)
{
    if(B.length <= 1)
    {
        return B;
    }

    int midpoint = B.length/2;
    int[] left = new int[midpoint];
    int[] right;
    if(B.length %2 == 0)
    {
        right = new int[midpoint];
    }
    else
    {
        right = new int[midpoint+1];
    }

    int [] result = new int [B.length];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < midpoint; i++)
    {
        left[i] = B[i];
    }

    int x=0;
    for (int j = midpoint; j < B.length; j++)
    {
        if(x < right.length)
        {
            right[x] = B[j];
            x++;
        }
    }

    left = merge_sort(left); // merge results into left 
    right = merge_sort(right); //merge results into right

    result = merge(left, right); // combine both results in merge

    return result; // return result

}

public static int []merge(int [] left, int [] right)
{

    int lengthResult = left.length + right.length;
    int [] result = new int [lengthResult];
    int indexL = 0;
    int indexR = 0;
    int indexRes = 0;
    while(indexL < left.length || indexR < right.length)
    {
        if(indexL < left.length && indexR < right.length)
        {
            if (left[indexL] <= right[indexR])
            {
                result [indexRes] = right[indexL];
                indexL++;
                indexRes++;
            }
            else
            {
                result [indexRes] = right[indexR];
                indexR++;
                indexRes++;
            }
        }

        else if (indexL < left.length)
        {
            result [indexRes] = left[indexL];
            indexL++;
            indexRes++;
        }
        else if (indexR < right.length)
        {
            result [indexRes] = right[indexR];
            indexR++;
            indexRes++;
        }
    }

    return result;

}

public static void printA (int [] B)
{
    for(int i=0; i < B.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(B[i]+" ");
    }
}

public static int[] populateA(int [] B)
{
    for(int i=0; i < B.length; i++)
    {
        B[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100); // Generate random numbers to fill array size
    }
    return B;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't pass two arrays. Instead, you should pass just one
   array with indices `left`, `right`, `mid`. Check [this](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Java/MergeSort_Recursive.html) link.
2. Merge sort does not **swap** the elements. If you are talking about displacement, then you should calculate the difference of the old index and new index of an element.

Comment: Actually, passing two arrays is just fine for getting the job done. Either way works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet more carefully, you have a typo there (accessing `right` instead of `left`):

```
if (left[indexL] <= right[indexR])
{
  result [indexRes] = right[indexL];
  indexL++;
  indexRes++;
}
else
{
  result [indexRes] = right[indexR];
  indexR++;
  indexRes++;
}
```

Speaking of swaps, merge sort does not normally swap elements as other sorting algorithm do, but you can compare `indexL` and `indexR` to get a similar measure. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712966/mergesort-swaps-and-comparisons) for more details.